# Is there a standard notation for a right-inverse?

Tags: functions, notation

I have a map $\phi:A\to B$ (i.e. from domain $A$ to codomain $B$), and a map $\psi:B\to A$.

The map $\psi$ is a right-inverse to $\phi$ in the sense that the map $\phi\circ\psi:B\to B$ is the identity map on $B$. However, $\psi$ is not a surjection onto $A$, hence $\psi\circ\phi:A\to A$ is not the identity map and $\psi$ is not a true inverse of $\phi$.

Because of the right-inverse relationship, I would very much like to use the same base symbol for $\psi$ and $\phi$. Thus far I've been using $\phi'$, but this seems like it might confuse the reader (this is the only instance where I use a prime in this way), even if I define it differently.

Is it appropriate to use $\phi^{-1}$ with a disclaimer that the map is only a right-inverse?

Alternatively, I seem to recall seeing notation $\phi^{\circ}$ for right-involutions in group theory. Would this be an appropriate use here?

Is there some other accepted notation?

Comment: I don't think you'll do better than $\phi \circ \psi = \mathrm{id}$. A similar problem shows up with adjoint functors, and you just have to be clear each time which is the left and which is the right adjoint.

Comment: Do not use $\phi^{-1}.$ A right inverse is not always unique, and the inverse function notation implies uniqueness.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson: OK, thanks.